# How can I remove an svg element from Dom using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to remove an svg from the DOM when mouse hover, my code :

```
$(".thumb").mouseenter(function() {

    $('.grayscale').toggleClass('grayscale-off');


    $('.thumb.grayscale > .grayscale-off').svg.text("");

  });
```

Here, I try to remove  element only from hovered element but svg.text(""); doesint work.

Any suggestion ?

Thank you!

Comment: What does the HTML/SVG look like?

Comment: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50" version="1.1"><image filter="url(&quot;#gray&quot;)" preserveAspectRatio="none meet" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  /></svg>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with SVG is the same as with any other dom node,
try this:

```
$('.thumb.grayscale > .grayscale-off').find('svg').remove();
```